# Flutterプロジェクトの開発環境の変更方法（Windows<=>Mac）について知りたい

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

現在WindowsのAndroidStudioで開発をしています。
そのプロジェクトをMacのAndroidStudioに移行したいと思っていますが、そのままコピーではFilePathの形式や場所などの問題でプロジェクトをビルドしたり実行することができません。

MacからWindowsに移行したときは、エラーが起きたところを全てテキストエディタを用いて手動で書き換えて対応しましたが、かなり面倒ですし、必要なところ全て書き換えられたかもわかりません。

環境を移行（WindowsからMac、MacからWindowsのどちらも）した時に行うべき、正しい方法(例えばCleanとか？)がわかりません。

VS Codeに移行する方法も併せて知りたいです。

Googleで検索しましたが、調べ方が悪いのか、思うような移行方法がヒットしてきません。

移行方法や、それの書かれたページでもいいので教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

移行元からは既存プロジェクトのフォルダをそのままコピーし、移行先では Android Studio の File メニューから "Import Project" を選ぶ方法があるようです。

[How do I export an Android Studio project? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18612588)

公式のドキュメントには以下のような記載があります。

[既存のプロジェクトをインポートする | Android デベロッパー](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project?hl=ja#ImportAProject)

> 既存のローカル プロジェクトを Android Studio にインポートする手順は次のとおりです。
>
> 1. [File] > [New] > [Import Project] をクリックします。
> 2. 表示されるウィンドウで、インポートするプロジェクトのルート ディレクトリに移動します。
> 3. [OK] をクリックします。

Comment: 上記方法に加え Tools>Flutter>Flutter Clean を行うことによって、開発環境の移行ができました。ありがとうございました。